# Design pattern for a sortable queue in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, design-patterns

I am trying to store a sortable queue in App engine.  Sortable as in the user can create a custom order.  Simplest way to think about it would be a list of songs.  Every 5 minuets a new song is chosen from the list and played.  But a user can add new songs and adjust the play order of the list.  Once a song is played it is removed from the list.  How do I do this for a large number of songs in the list.

I thought about adding a sortOrder field, but whenever a song is played, I need to update the whole list.  I then though of keeping a floating sort order, and just track highest and lowest entry but this seems like it could lead to trouble if many songs are being added at once.

Any information about design patterns I can look at for this would be very appreciated.  Also, is there any way I could use the unique key values of the songs to order my list.  Am I guaranteed all new ids will be greater than ones created earlier in time, or is there a way I can guarantee this?

Comment: I am still not clear on what you want to do... It seems to me that your question is more about data structures than design patterns. Any reason that you cannot use something along the lines of a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)?

Comment: I need to store this to be stored in the datastore, not in memory.  Multiple people will be editing the list and making changes over a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an ordered queue which you can arbitrarily rearrange or add/remove elements from. If that's the case, you can use a linked list, which is really a data structure, rather than a design pattern.

See [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

So for example you can use `remove(int index)` to remove a song at any position in the list whilst retaining the ordering. Equivalently you can use `add(int index, Object element)` to insert a song at any index in the list whilst retaining the ordering. There's other utility methods in there also, but that seems like the basis for implementing what you need.

Comment: This works in a single request, but I am trying to store these in the datastore, not in memory.

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from persisting the linked list. It's a [rudimentary data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) which can be implemented anywhere

Comment: But in order to use this list I need to bring all of my values into memory.  This is not efficient for very large lists 100,000+ entities,  especially when all I care about is the first one and where to place the last one.

Comment: No, you don't. The whole point of a linked list is that each element simply points to the next. The value of the pointer can be anything. For example it could be the primary key of the element in a database table. The first element in the list is the one with a pointer value of null, the last one is the one with nothing pointing to it.